# Can Ansible use SCM (GIT) vault file?

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

We are working on using Ansible/Ansible Tower to deploy some of development environments.  We also are leveraging the Tower's ability to integrate with SCM (in our case, GIT).

This work is progressing but we have several (3-4) independent development environments and for the deployment processes (installing and configuring) we have need/use a set of passwords, and the passwords are different for each environment.

We would like to use the/leverage the Ansible vault for the passwords but it seems that if we do that, there would be only one vault for all the environments, so we are how we could be able to have a different vault for each environment?

I have seen some info about "vault-password-fileparameters", but it seems like that parameter needs to point to a directory/file path on a drive, whereas I think that ideally, what we would like is to be able to set the "vault-password-fileparameters" to something like a URL pointing to our SCM, similar to how, in Tower, you can specify the SCM URL and the SCM BRANCH/TAG/COMMIT, i.e., so we could set "vault-password-fileparameters" to point to the SCM and branch or commit that we want to use for the Vault file.

So I was wondering:  Is that possible?  Is there a way that Ansible can do that?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: From tower/awx, you don't use a vault password file: you create a credential that will be used to decrypt the vault encrypted files/vars/values encountered by your playbook. If you have used several ids to encrypt your data, you can provide all needed ones.

Comment: Going over the related [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) and [tower](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#vault) documentations might help.

Comment: Regarding your exact question (but I do not think this is the real problem here): you can declare as vault password file (or in your vault identity list) an executable file of your choice. In the case of vault-id it will receive the id as a parameter. The file should output the password which will be used. I actually use this daily for more that thee years to retreive my different vault id password from my ubuntu keystore (unlocked when I login). I don't see anything that would prevent you to call a uri in that script. But storing an encryption password in an scm is a really bad idea.

Comment: Zeitounator - by your last comment above, were you referring to vault_identity_list?  And by "declare ..an executable", did you mean something like the last comment by drzraf at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13243 (e.g., the "executables" would be the 2 comma-separated shell scripts in that case)?

Answer (score 0):

How about inventories? you use an inventory for each environment.

Each inventory will contain a group of hosts plus the vaulted passwords.

Here more details about inventories : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/inventories.html

So you organize your hosts inside your inventories, let's say `dev` inventory and `qa` inventory, each one has a couple of defined group hosts for example database group, webserver group, and you use the group_vars folder inside each inventory to store the vaulted password there, let's call it `db_root_password`, this variable is defined in each inventory inside the specific group.

So your inventory project structure will be something like this:

```
- inventory/dev/group_vars/vars.yml
- inventory/qa/group_vars/vars.yml
```

Inside each file, you put your specific inventory variables, such as `db_root_password`

For the host file of each inventory, for `dev` environment it'll be in `inventory/dev/hosts`

and it'll contains your groups:

```
 db-01  ansible_host="192.168.1.1"
 web-01 ansible_host="192.168.1.2"

 [database]
 db-01

 [webserver]
 web-01
```

If your import this inventory in your Ansible Tower, it'll be organized in your inventory section.

I hope this helps you understand the idea.

Comment: I think we already are using inventories but for hostnames.  (I am not an Ansible expert) but I have the impression that the vault is where secure values (like passwords) are supposed to be stored.  FYI, we DO have another way, involving using env vars (this is in Linux), but they want to "standardize" to use the "correct" way for passwords, which would be using the vault in Ansible?

Comment: Sorry to add on, but also, BTW, the passwords that I am referring to are not just for logging into a machine, but also things like passwords for databases, etc.

Comment: I updated my answer above to give an example of how you structure your passwords and variables per inventory